# Weird password mask when using jQueryUI Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

So i'm using a standard asp.net textbox in password mode on a jQuery UI dialog box and in all browsers except for IE the password mask looks normal.  IE in all the versions i have tried all look like boxes.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

[image]

Edit: The password masking works correctly on the *main page*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What font is being used by jQueryUI for these textboxes?  Normally an appearance like this means that the font doesn't contain the character it's trying to use.

Comment: Right from the Redmond Theme. *Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif* **but** as it turns out it was just the font! why would jQuery UI use that in one of the default themes?